# Is there an alternative to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with no timezone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I need to store the date a row was inserted into a table, and so far I have this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    inserted_on timestampz DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

This works, but really I don't need the time zone (which is included by `timestampz`). Is there an alternative to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP that doesn't return the time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `localtimestamp`.  The data type is `timestamp without timezone`:

```
 select localtimestamp, pg_typeof(localtimestamp)
```